# Xamarin.UITest is not able to enter text for Acr.UserDialogs box on Samsung Devices

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I am having an issue where both `app.ClearText()` and `app.EnterText()` is not working for Acr.UserDialogs box on Samsung Devices (see attached screenshot) however works on Pixel. I am not sure what I can do to work around this, I have already tried to use `[![app.Query(e => e.Id("custom").Invoke("setText", string.Empty))][1]][1]` and this is not working as well. I have found no way that Xamarin.UITest is able to change the text of these dialog boxes and I am really hoping there is a workaround or something I am missing. Thank you for your help in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to repro and test your scenario with the Acr.UserDialogs. App.SetText doesn't work as the item is not focused and as I already figured out, you need to use a query.
My query doesn't work because e.Id("custom") is not an EditText element but its container. So modifying query to app.Query(e => e.Id("custom").Descendant().Invoke("setText", string.Empty)) does work.

Comment: You just saved me hours of bug hunting. Many many thanks for this simple, yet effective solution.